# How to disable concrete function onload page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, disable

How to globaly disable javascript function named for example ABC in JQuery after page loading?

Comment: Why not just simply remove the function if you don't want it to run?

Comment: Because an external js file, where I have no access :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to put the snippet before any of your other JS that calls this function. But this should do the trick.

```
//On page load 
$(function(){
  //if the function exists
  if($.ABC != undefined){
    //Overwrite function
    $.ABC = function(){}; //Empty function, does nothing
  }
});
```

I made it an empty function, in case its being used as a function in other places. Ensures the JS doesn't break. If the function in question is supposed to return something, maybe specify a default return value as well.

I'm also assuming this is a jquery function, but if not, this should also do the trick for just a regular function:

```
//On page load
$(function(){
   // if ABC is defined
   if(ABC != undefined){
      //overwrite
      ABC = function(){};
   }
});
```

Comment: Just use regular `window.onload` if you don't want to use the jquery version :)

Comment: this solution doesn't work on anonymous functions, and usually onload functions are anonymous

Comment: @Aurangzeb OP didn't specify its an anonymous function though. But you're right that's almost impossible to access unless you have a key to modify it, but even then, the function might already be run internally before you can override it.

Comment: @Jirin Happy to help! Can you mark my post as the solution? :) Cheers

Comment: I'd like, I tried a few days ago ... but: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." :( ... I have 11 only ... exist some way, hot to have 15 and more? :)